# req returns undefined ~ Express Post Request using Postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman, body-parser

I'm a complete beginner using node.js and express.

I've currently got the following code running in Node JS.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todos', (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

When I make a POST request using Postman to `localhost:3000/todos`, I do indeed get a console log which return an object as defined in my POST request body.

However, when I comment out `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and send the same POST request from Postman, `undefined` is returned to the console. I was expecting a string to be returned at least. Why is `undefined` only returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body-parser` parses the request body i.e. `req.body` without it there is no req.body.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser